# c# Access database read error

Tags: c#, ms-access

I want to read from database with this code.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    connection.Open();

    OleDbCommand parancs = new OleDbCommand();
    parancs.Connection = connection;
    parancs.CommandText= "select * from table where Nev='"+textBox1.Text+"' and Jelszo='"+textBox2.Text+"'";

    OleDbDataReader olvas = parancs.ExecuteReader();
    MessageBox.Show("SIKERES BEJELENTKEZES");
    connection.Close();
}
```

but I get this error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

first off your `connection` is undefined

you want to really use a `using` around all of this to make it a lot nicer and will close the connection for you when done. Using a `using statement block` in which the object created is closed, flushed and disposed and the resources are then allowed to be used again by other processes. This ensures that the framework would take the best measures for each process.

The below will work just make sure you set your connection string in it.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection()) 
    {
       conn.ConnectionString = "your connection_string";
       conn.Open();

      // Create the command
      SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select * from table where Nev= @firstParmeter and Jelszo= @secondParameter", conn);
      // Add the parameters.
      command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("firstParmeter", textBox1.Text));
      command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("secondParameter", textBox2.Text));

      // Create new SqlDataReader object and read data from the command.
      using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
      {
        // while there is another record present
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            // set what you want here as it will be reading all the rows from the query example below
            // write the data on to the screen
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} \t | {1} \t | {2} \t | {3}",
            // call the objects from their index
            reader[0], reader[1], reader[2], reader[3]));

        }
      }
    }
}
```